# Can't seem to extend the WSDL from the local directory

Tags: api, soap, wsdl

Very new to Magento and having some issues extending it.

I need to add some attributes to the existing SOAP API.

I have the code working to add those attributes and if I add them to the WSDL and the WSI in the core it works fine, but whenever I remove them from the core and add files to the etc location in my local code dir it fails to work.

Specifically the API I am updating is `salesOrderInfo`.

I have created my override file inside /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php

I have put the following code in this location: /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
            <all>
               <element name="pvx_line_price" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>
```

and the other one is here: /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
         targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <xsd:complexType name="salesOrderItemEntity">
            <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="pvx_line_price" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

I have tried so many times to work out what caches I might need to disable, rebuild etc but I've hit pretty much the end of my tether on this one. I've exhausted all the googling and tutorials I can find. I am basically following what I think should work.

Please bear in mind in your reply I am new to Magento so may not know how to do what you are describing. That said I am not new to PHP. It has to be said in all the years I have never found such a complex system to extend.

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes please, if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new module under `local` and put extension wsdl.xml to `app/code/local/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/wsdl.xml`. Then it will be correctly merged into resulting WSDL document.

Comment: As I am certain I tried that over and over for a couple of days with tiny variations, can you be very specific (as in file by file). I know that is a pain, but I've hit the point where I have all but given up.

Comment: Just don't use the same path as for core config `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/etc/wsi.xml`, create custom module and add extension configuration there. I'm almost sure that overriding for classes in `local` works because it is supported by autoloader, but for configs it will not work as you expected.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but I am very new to Magento and I have tried a lot of things. So far you are describing something I have tried. Unless you are going to give me a file by file or step by step guide I don't know what is different about what you are suggesting.

Comment: Create new module as described [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/) and put your `wsi.xml` and `wsdl.xml` there (they both look good)

Comment: OK, I followed that tutorial as far as the title "Defining An Event Observer" (aka, when they finished the initial part of creating the folders and the config file).


My plugin is enabled and showing in the config pages. I then added my files to the etc directory in my plugin and refreshed the cache, recompiled and refreshed the WSDL on this url: /index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1


It does not contain any of my settings. This is what I did before.

Comment: Can you try to put your `wsdl.xml` under `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc` ? Just to understand if the problem is in the file itself or new custom module under `local` is not properly declared

Comment: Adminhtml? I assume this is just because any old core module should work?

Anyway, no change

Comment: Just tried and it worked for me: 1. Created `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/wsdl.xml` 2. Put your content to it and added missing `</definitions>` at the end 3. Cleared `var/cache` 4. Reloaded WSDL page and searched for `pvx_line_price` . WS-I mode is off (configured in the admin) and WSDL caching in SOAP Server PHP extension is off.

Comment: OK, it turns out your last comment was the kicker. "added missing </definitions>" That was the only issue.

Thankyou